# How to pass data to custom TCPDF class?

Tags: php, pdf, tcpdf

I have this so far:

```
class MYPDF extends TCPDF {

  public function Header(){}

  public function Footer(){}

}
```

I'd like to do something like this

```
class MYPDF extends TCPDF {

    protected $info;

    public function setInfo($info){
        $this->info = $info;
    }
    public function Header(){
         // use $info here
    }
    public function Footer(){
        //use $info here
    }
}
```

BUt it doesn't seem to like it...when I create an instance of MYPDF and setInfo, it doesn't seem to be reading it from Header or Footer.

Answer (score 5):

in your Header and Footer functions access the variable as `$this->info`

Answer (score 2):

Header and Footer have their `$this->getHeaderData()` and and `$this->getFooterData()` respectively which can be set from outside the class with setHeaderData and setFooterData. [see sourceforce discussion](https://sourceforge.net/p/tcpdf/discussion/435311/thread/505a9e13/#db72)

Answer (score 0):

There are built in functions called Header and Footer in TCPDF Class. 
Documentation could be found here: http://www.tcpdf.org/doc/classTCPDF.html

Answer (score 0):

If outside data or variable is to pass in the header or footer function then separately need to call connection with **include** keyword. Remember **require_once** does not work here. example-

```
include ("../../inc/my_con.php");
```

This is not exactly your solution but you can try this concept.